# WPF MVVM ListView: Change "SelectedItem" in ViewModel Property

Tags: validation, binding, listbox

So, this is my frist post on stackoverflow... Before I was able to solve every problem on research.

Now, I have an simple usecase an I couldn't find a simple solution. (Found: Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke/Interaction Trigger with command - and I don't like it)

I wrote an application using MVVM: `<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding StringList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedString}">` (`StringList` is an `ObservableCollection<string>` with "a", "b", "c")

My problem: I like to set the selection to "b" if the user select "c". But after `RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedString");` and a `return "b"` from getter the Listview selection is still  "c"...

```
public string SelectedString
{
   get 
   { 
      return _selectedString; 
   }
   set
   {
      if (value == "c")
         _selectedString = "b";
      else
         _selectedString = value;

      RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedString");
   }
}
```

Are there simple solutions? Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always do it the hard way: create a new listview, bind it's visibility to a Boolean which will be dependent on the case when you have to change the selection like you are doing in your "if". And when this case takes place, hide the first listview and show the second (don't forget to bind the second's listview SelectedItem to some other string).